# Bokeh: trigger CustomJS from client-side event

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

Is it possible have a Bokeh plot listen for a client-side event and then trigger a CustomJS callback in response? I would prefer to not have to utilize a bokeh server to accomplish this.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "client side event" ?

Comment: I mean in the sense of having bokenJS listen for an event which happens _outside_ of the bokeh plot, and then react to it. For example, if the bokeh plot was meant to display user data, the plot could listen for a 'UserLogIn' event (perhaps broadcast by a call to document.dispatchEvent ) and then trigger an ajax call containing the user's credentials to update a ColumnDataSource object.

Another route would be to directly manipulate the ColumnDataSource object on the client side outside via some arbitrary js code (as in, not code which is defined via a CustomJS object). Is this possible?